# Replace multiple newlines, tabs, and spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace multiple newline characters with one newline character, and multiple spaces with a single space.

I tried `preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n", $text);` and failed!

I also do this job on the $text for formatting.

```
$text = wordwrap($text, 120, '<br/>', true);
$text = nl2br($text);
```

$text is a large text taken from user for BLOG, and for a better formatting I use wordwrap.

Comment: You failed? What went wrong? And can you paste a bit of the code around?

Comment: i've mentioned both of the things

Comment: @Sourav - It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. From the looks of it, the blog post is in plain text and you want to place a line break after every 120 words (wordwrap) and again to replace new lines (nl2br). When exactly do you want to replace multiple new lines with a single one?

Comment: @Francois Deschenes i want to do the regex/preg then wrap then nl2br !

Comment: @Sourav - See my updated answer below.

Comment: I can't help but think that you're making this much more complicated than it should be.  HTML already handles word wrapping beautifully, why would you manually add line breaks to text that has characters with dynamic width?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In theory, you regular expression does work, but the problem is that not all operating system and browsers send only \n at the end of string. Many will also send a \r.

Try:

I've simplified this one:

```
preg_replace("/(\r?\n){2,}/", "\n\n", $text);
```

And to address the problem of some sending \r only:

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]{2,}/", "\n\n", $text);
```

Based on your update:

```
// Replace multiple (one ore more) line breaks with a single one.
$text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);

$text = wordwrap($text,120, '<br/>', true);
$text = nl2br($text);
```

Comment: And some send `\r` only ;) - And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Sourav - In your example above, you were replacing 2 or more \n with a 2 \n hence my example. If you only want 1 (i.e. to skip a line but without leaving an empty line in-between), simply replace the \n\n with \n.

Comment: i also needed the `$text = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $text);` anyway thanks :)

Comment: You can simplify multi-line replacement further to this: `preg_replace("/(\R){2,}/", "$1", $str);`

Comment: If the text you are formatting has space(s) before, after, or between the newlines, this cleans those up: `$text = preg_replace("/(\s*[\r\n]\s*)+/", "\n", $text);`

Comment: @ironic_ollins `/(\s*[\r\n]\s*)+/` messes with code formatting and moves everything to the start of the line.
`/(\R\s*\R)+/` works better and preserves remaining code formatting. 
So should use `$text = preg_replace("/(\R\s*\R)+/", "\n\n", $text);`

Answer (score 42):

> Use \R (which represents any line ending sequence):

```
$str = preg_replace('#\R+#', '</p><p>', $str);
```

It was found here: *[Replacing two new lines with paragraph tags](https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/169162-solved-replacing-two-new-lines-with-paragraph-tags/)*

PHP documentation about [Escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> \R (line break: matches \n, \r and \r\n)

Answer (score 12):

This is the answer, as I understand the question:

```
// Normalize newlines
preg_replace('/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/', "\n", $text);
// Replace whitespace characters with a single space
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
```

---

This is the actual function that I use to convert new lines to HTML line break and paragraph elements:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
function nl2html($text)
{
    return '<p>' . preg_replace(array('/(\r\n\r\n|\r\r|\n\n)(\s+)?/', '/\r\n|\r|\n/'),
            array('</p><p>', '<br/>'), $text) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: you got me right but the code did not executed properly [WinXP, FF]

Comment: Did you get an error? What's the error? I use a similar replace in my app.

Comment: for some reason (W7 OS) this didn't work... although I think it should!  I also tried with square brackets... still failed to work... hmm, there's obviously something about preg_replace which I don't understand... wonder what OS you were using...

Comment: The server is Linux. On Windows, it might convert "\n" to a carriage return and line feed.

Answer (score 2):

You need the multiline modifier to match multiple lines:

```
preg_replace("/PATTERN/m", "REPLACE", $text);
```

Also in your example you seem to be replacing 2+ newlines with exactly 2, which isn't what your question indicates.

Comment: ignore my preg_replace, i know thats faulty.

Comment: I thought the multiline modifier is making `^` and `$` catch the beginning and the end of a line, not that `\n` matches `\n`.

Comment: @hakre - You're absolute correct. In this case, the m modifier in not necessary.

Comment: @Chris - The + means 1 or more so in theory, @Sourav could be replacing many additional \n. I don't see anything wrong with the use of the + sign here.

Comment: @Francois: yeah... I know... that's why I said "2+" newlines -- as in 2 or more. @hakre: good point, I didn't realize that was only useful for regexes with anchors.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of above, but it didn't work for me. Then I created some long way to resolve that issue...

Before :

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

After :

```
$tempData = nl2br($text);
$tempData = explode("<br />",$tempData);

foreach ($tempData as $val) {
   if(trim($val) != '')
   {
      echo $val."<br />";
   }
}
```

And it's worked for me.. I wrote here because, if somebody came here to find answer like me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
preg_replace("/(\R){2,}/", "$1", $str);
```

This will take care of all the Unicode newline characters.

Comment: @Sourav: I think you should call `preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r){2,}/", "$1", $text);` before call to `nl2br`.

Comment: i'm calling preg_replace before nl2br and wrap !

Comment: That's good, then pls tell me what problem you're getting when you used `preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r){2,}/", "$1", $text);`

Comment: i'm supposed to get only a single br for any number of br but i'm getting upto 3 br

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a sample text in your question. I can quickly see where those extra `<br>` are coming from although I sense `nl2br` is probably doing that. You can also try commenting this call for testing and see if that improves the result.

Comment: `<br>
<br>
$text = wordwrap($text,120, ‘&lt;br/&gt;‘, true);<br>
$text = nl2br($text);<br>
<br>` for the highlighted code in the question.

Comment: What I meant was can you add some sample content of `$text` variable in your question so that I can simulate your problem at my end.

Comment: i copied all the content of this page and tested in FF 3.6

Comment: You can simplify it to this:
`preg_replace("/(\R){2,}/", "$1", $str);`

Comment: Very good suggestion @Paul as this answer was pretty old. I have added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace multiple tabs with a single tab, use the following code.

```
preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "\t", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]*/", "\r\n", $text);
```

Comment: I'm interested what happens when this is executed.

Comment: Because the string you're matching contains newlines, you will probably need to use the `m` pattern modifier.  See http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the head and the end of string or document!

```
preg_replace('/(^[^a-zA-Z]+)|([^a-zA-Z]+$)/','',$match);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with strip_tags function in PHP and had some problems like: after having a linebreak then appear a new line with some spaces and then a new linebreak appear continuously ...etc. without any rule :(.

**This is my solution for dealing with strip_tags**

**Replace multiple spaces to one, multiple linebreaks to single linebreak**

```
function cleanHtml($html)
{
    // Clean code into script tags
    $html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html);

    // Clean code into style tags
    $html = preg_replace('/<\s*style.+?<\s*\/\s*style.*?>/si', '', $html );

    // Strip HTML
    $string = trim(strip_tags($html));

    // Replace multiple spaces on each line (keep linebreaks) with single space
    $string = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/", " ", $string); // (*)

    // Replace multiple spaces of all positions (deal with linebreaks) with single linebreak
    $string = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', "\n", $string); // (**)
    return $string;
}
```

Keywords are (*) and (**).