# Combine regular expressions for spaces and line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i merge the following into one regex?

```
    str
        .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") // get rid of line breaks 
        .replace(/\s/g, ""); // get rid of spaces
```

I want to call replace() once and take care of both in same regex

Comment: Did you try anything? You could at least add another alternative to the end of the first pattern and check. However, `\s` matches `\n` and `\r`, so `\s` is enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394416/replace-excess-whitespaces-and-line-breaks-with-php

Comment: str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"") fixed it

Comment: @shmnsw You do not need to match `\r` and `\n`... See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you only need to be using `\s`... that normally includes `[\r\n\t\f ]`, so the first replace is basically useless.

https://regex101.com/r/eX7sE7/1

Answer (score 0):

[regexr.com](http://regexr.com) is a great tool for testing regular expressions as it explains what each part does. for example if you hover over a `/s` it will tell you that it matches line breaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

use this  `str.replace(/(\s)/g,"");`