# Remove All Kinds of Tabs, White Space, Carriage Return In A String in PHP

Tags: php

I have text data like this:

```
                Learn More

        Hide [x]








                            Colors



                    Fetching Colors description...




            Show more topics







                            Art exhibitions



                    Fetching Art exhibitions description...








                            Abstract art



                    Fetching Abstract art description...








                            Representational art



                    Fetching Representational art description...
```

I'd like to be able to remove all the carriage returns, so it becomes like this:

```
Learn More Hide [x] Colors Fetching Colors description... Show more topics
```

How do I do this in PHP? Note that the strings might be UTF-8 string, and we need to take into account various kinds of tab, carriage return and white space characters. (I am thinking along the lines of a tokeniser algorithm used in a compiler, where multiple carriage return and white space characters are taken care of.)

Comment: possibly duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394416/replace-excess-whitespaces-and-line-breaks-with-php 

and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space

Answer (score 5):

You can try this with a preg_replace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$data = preg_replace('/[\s\t\n]{2,}/', ' ', $data);
```

You can learn more about regular expressions where:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

You can test them live here:
https://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace **multiple** spaces to **single** space instead of removing tabs(`\t`), spaces(`\s`), carriage return(`\r`) or line feed(`\n`)

```
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $your_input_string_with_multi_space_goes);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/XMoVr