# How can I remove all extra/unwanted whitespaces from a string?

Tags: php

I am extracting some strings from HTML pages and sometimes i end up with contents like this:

```
...
       <div>
           This is a sample text that extends
           over several lines, with linebreaks
           in the HTML code and with indentation 
           spaces to the left.
       </div>
...
```

When I extract the text within the `<div>` and store it in a string it will contain both a lot of extra spaces and linebreak characters. I wish to convert the string to a "one-line-string", i.e. removing unnecessary spaces and linebreaks. Here's a conceptual part of the code:

```
<?php
    $my_textpart = extract_textpart_from_div();
    $my_string   = remove_unwanted_whitespaces($my_textpart);
    // --> $my_string = "This is a sample text that extends over several lines, with linebreaks in ... etc ..."
?>
```

Is there a neat or smart PHP function that may help me here, or will I be forced to write a function where I use `str_replace` in a loop to remove double spaces and linebreaks until all extra whitespaces are removed?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394416/replace-excess-whitespaces-and-line-breaks-with-php)

Comment: Splendid! That helped me enough! Thanks both of you