# Convert String with Line Breaks into Single Line With Line Breaks Still Intact

Tags: php, html, string

I have the following string:

```
Hello Eric,

Thank you very much for the links. This was exactly what I needed.

Greetings,
John
```

I am using php's `nl2br` function to convert new lines into line breaks which is working correctly. After I run the `nl2br` function on my string, it becomes this:

```
Hello Eric,<br />

Thank you very much for the links. This was exactly what I needed.<br />

Greetings,<br />
John
```

So far, this is what I am trying to achieve. However, I now need to convert the new string with line breaks into a single line as so:

```
Hello Eric,<br />Thank you very much for the links. This was exactly what I needed.<br />Greetings,<br />John
```

I have tried several different methods but none seem to work. Here are a few things I have tried:

`$str = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$str);`

`$str = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "", $str);`

`$str = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $str);`

None of these work for me though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace Multiple Newline, Tab, Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space)

Comment: @Rizier123 None of those solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"",$str);
```

Instead of

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$str);
```

Can be watched at:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41a6fbd2c937418fce927b31f6ab74ad30f8b4d0

Read more about line breaks characters here:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations