# how to remove multiple whitespaces and newline character from HTML entity

Tags: string, codeigniter, newline, simple-html-dom, removing-whitespace

I am trying to implement a crawler using codeigniter and simplehtmldom.

```
$page = "URL to be Crawled";
$html = file_get_html($page);
$ad_description = $html->find('#ad_description',-1);
$description = $ad_description->innertext;
```

`$description` contains multiple consecutive spaces and newline which I need to convert in to single appearances.

I tried

```
str_replace("\n\r",' ',$description),
reduce_multiples($ad_description->innertext,"\r")
preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $description)
ascii_to_entities($description,ENT_HTML5, "ISO-8859-1")
```

and many other possible options but without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may get idea from his http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space

Comment: Even preg_replace did not work.

Comment: I have even tried combinations of the above options. none of them worked. The find() function returns HTML entity which is not bound by a normal string operation. If someone could suggest on how to convert this entity into string. May be the above options would work.

Comment: can you echo or var_dump $description

Comment: Yes I can echo description it echoes multiple newlines and multiple spaces

Answer (score 0):

i think that pref_replace does work

```
$description = "This
is      a
test   string
";

echo $description = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $description); // This is a test string
```

Comment: The above context definitely works. But it is not working when I use $html->find()

Comment: show `var_dump($description);` before and afer `preg_replace`