# Remove blank lines from txt file keeping carriage returns

Tags: php, blank-line

I have a text file with, say, this content:

[image]

I need to remove blank lines, but keeping the existing carriage returns, like this:

[image]

The code I'm using:

```
if ($file = fopen("file.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        echo str_replace("\r\n","",$line)
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

As stated above, I have tried with functions like str_replace, preg_replace, and \r\n or \n\n, etc. as characters to replace, but with all of them I'm getting this result:

[image]

The blank line is removed as desired, but carriage returns are removed too, which it's not allowed in my case.

So I wonder if anyone could suggest a way to get my goal.

Comment: replace any 2 or more line breaks in a row with a single one

Comment: does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space

Answer (score 1):

There are bound to be duplicates for the replacing, but simply read into an array and skip the empty lines:

```
$lines = file("file.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES):
```

Then loop the array to `echo` the lines or `implode()` to get it back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove blank lines and space. From a random text file.
It will automatically remove blank lines and blank space just add the location of file and print it.

Use this code

```
    __DIR__ . "/uploads/" . $randomFile;
    $file_handle = fopen('uploads/' . $randomFile, 'r');
    // $file_handle2 = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/m', '', $randomFile);
    function get_all_lines($file_handle)
    {
      while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        yield fgets($file_handle);
      }
    }
    $count = 0;
    foreach (get_all_lines($file_handle) as $line) {
      $line = implode("\n", array_filter(explode("\n", $line)));
      $newLine = trim($line);
      $tempData = nl2br($line);
      $tempData = explode("<br />", $tempData);
      foreach ($tempData as $line) {
        if (trim($line) != '') {
          //  echo $line."<br />";
          echo (' <li>' . $line . '</li>');
        }
      }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Abracadaver @nogad @GCRdev

I've bee trying your methods, but didn't work for me. I finally found a way (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20719126), which I let it here if it is useful for someone:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt","r");
while($line = fgets($file)){

    $tempData = nl2br($line);
    $tempData = explode("<br />",$tempData);

    foreach ($tempData as $val) {
       if(trim($val) != '')
       {
          echo $val."<br />";
       }
    }
}
fclose($file);
```