# How to make csv import work on both mac and windows

Tags: php, regex, laravel, csv, laravel-5

I simply would like to import this text from a [csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vUrs2m-Oc8TbmwySPgRFOse2_VbAqDe7UWXXZCE-rR0/edit#gid=1918513577) into a laravel php script that parses it:

```
store_id,ref,priority,tagline
10,confuscian,5,confuscian says
```

when I send this on a mac machine on chrome, the body of the csv appears like this:

[image]

[image]

so you can see that a `\n` is added:

```
{"csv":"store_id,ref,priority,tagline\n10,confuscian,5,confuscian says"}
```

however, when I add the same csv from windows, it appears like so:

```
{"csv":"store_id,ref,priority,tagline 10,confuscian,5,confuscian says"}
```

the script that reads this filters out the `\r\n` [different OS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space/6360769#6360769) like so:

```
    $file = storage_path('batch_update.csv');
    // replace new line characters for mac/win/linux
    $str = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/', "\n", $this->data);
    file_put_contents($file, $str); 

    $this->data = $this->csvToArray($file);

    if (!$this->data || !$this->checkForRequiredColumns()) {
        return false;
    }
```

the problem is that in windows, the `\n` doesn't even show up! which confuses the csvToArray script:

```
trait CsvHelpers
{
    private function csvToArray($filename)
    {
        if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
            return false;
        }

        $header = null;
        $data   = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false) {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
                $row = array_map('trim', $row);
                if (!$header) {
                    $header = $row;
                } else {
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

## question

how do i make it so that when i export a csv in windows, every line ends in `\n`?

Comment: This probably won't fix your issue, but you can change your regex to `[\r\n]+` or `(?:\r\n?)+` (this won't replace double `\n`) to improve performance.

Comment: So, how is this csv being generated? Also, your screenshots appear to show you looking at the request payload in different views.

Comment: `however, when I add the same csv from windows, it appears like so...` like newline is replaced with a space character? No way.